# Can you give an example of comment channel message?

Tags: comments, channel, pyrogram

I don't understand how to comment on channels in Pyrogram
I hope you can give me an example of the comment channel. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Commenting on channels is the same as sending message because comments are basically replies to the auto-forwarded message (every channel message is auto forwarded to the linked group). The only difference is users can reply to the message without really being in the group.

If you already have the message (the group message):

```
await message.reply("See my comment")
```

Or you can get the message using id of the message in linked group. Look at the documentation of [get_discussion_message](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/get_discussion_message) for further.

Answer (score 0):

You should have access to post on the associated discussion group.
Then you can use the below script to send a message as a comment on **Pyrogram 2.0+**.
**Update**: Commenting with the channel profile is a Premium feature now, you should buy Telegram Premium to be able to choose your profile as a channel.

```py
from pyrogram import Client

Credentials = Client(
    name="comment_on_channel",
    api_id=---,
    api_hash="---",
    device_model="Comment On Channel",
    app_version="CoCh v1.0",
)

with Credentials as app:
    # Group's Numeric ID with corresponding -100 [integer]
    group_ID = -1001234567890
    # ID of the message that you want to reply to (ID of a post in the discussion group) [integer]
    msg_ID = 165

    app.send_message(
        chat_id=group_ID,
        reply_to_message_id=msg_ID,
        text="My Comment"
    )
```